# Getting error while creating mdb file on vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write an app on vb.net. I am using visual studio community 2013. In some point I have to create mdb file. I searched all over internet and try every suggestions but always I get error on adox as follows (marked with *)

```
Namespace ADOX
Class Catalog

    Sub Create(sCreateString As String)
       ***Throw New NotImplementedException***
    End Sub

End Class
End Namespace
```

my script quite long but this is what I use for create mdb file

```
    Option Explicit On
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Linq
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports ADOX
```

....

```
    Public Sub MakeADataBase(ByVal sDBName As String)
            Dim catArch = New ADOX.Catalog
            catArch.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sDBName & ";" & _
                    "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5")
            catArch = Nothing
            MessageBox.Show("done")
    End Sub
```

this code is working on new project but not working on my original project and always generate above error. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The mostly likely reason for this failure is that you're developing the program as a 64-bit application.  The Jet OLEDB driver is 32-bit only.

So, from visual studio, just use the "Configuration Manager" to change the "platform" to x86.